# $a_n , n=1,2,3..$ and $b_n, n=1,2,3..$ are convergent sequences. $c_n = a_n + b_n, n=1,2,3..$ Prove sequence $c_n, n=1,2,3...$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

I had to edit out some of the wording in the title as it is was too long, here is the full question:

Suppose $a_n , n=1,2,3...$ and $b_n, n=1,2,3...$ are convergent sequences. Let $c_n = a_n + b_n, n=1,2,3..$ Prove that sequence $c_n, n=1,2,3...$ is also convergent.

Could someone show me how to prove this? (Bearing in mind that this is my first encounter with analysis and these types of problems.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

we know that $c_n\to a+b$, where $a_n\to a$ and $b_n\to b$

Now $|c_n-(a+b)|=|a_n+b_n-(a+b)|=|(a_n-a)+(b_n-b)|\le |(a_n-a)|+|(b_n-b)|$ (triangle inequality)

Since $a_n\to a,\,b_n\to b$

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0\, \exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge N_1:|a_n-a|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2} $ and:

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0\, \exists N_2\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge N_2:|b_n-b|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2} $

Let $N^*=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and we have:

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0\, \exists N^*\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge N_1:|c_n-(a+b)|\le |(a_n-a)|+|(b_n-b)|\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

Thus $c_n\to a+b$ as $n\to\infty$